# Call different list with similar name in a for loop

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, variables

I have a few lists that are with names: group1, group2, group3...
I need a for loop (lets say for (int i=1; i<=6; i++) and right now I check for example if i is 1 then use group1, if i is 2 use group2 etc... My question is, can I call the list with the 'i' in the end? Like groupi and when i is 1, its group1, when i is 2, its group2 etc. Here is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < groupNum; i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        foreach (Player p1 in group1)
        {
            foreach (Player p2 in group1)
            {
                if (p1 != p2)
                {
                    if (group1.IndexOf(p1) > group1.IndexOf(p2))
                    {
                        Game game = new Game(tournamentID, p1.id, p2.id);
                        game.status = "Pending";
                        gm.CreateGame(game);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    else if (i == 1)
    {
        foreach (Player p1 in group2)
        {
            foreach (Player p2 in group2)
            {
                if (p1 != p2)
                {
                    if (group2.IndexOf(p1) > group2.IndexOf(p2))
                    {
                        Game game = new Game(tournamentID, p1.id, p2.id);
                        game.status = "Pending";
                        gm.CreateGame(game);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    else if (i == 2)
    {
        foreach (Player p1 in group3)
        {
            foreach (Player p2 in group3)
            {
                if (p1 != p2)
                {
                    if (group3.IndexOf(p1) > group3.IndexOf(p2))
                    {
                        Game game = new Game(tournamentID, p1.id, p2.id);
                        game.status = "Pending";
                        gm.CreateGame(game);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    else if (i == 3)
    {
        foreach (Player p1 in group4)
        {
            foreach (Player p2 in group4)
            {
                if (p1 != p2)
                {
                    if (group4.IndexOf(p1) > group4.IndexOf(p2))
                    {
                        Game game = new Game(tournamentID, p1.id, p2.id);
                        game.status = "Pending";
                        gm.CreateGame(game);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    else if (i == 4)
    {
        foreach (Player p1 in group5)
        {
            foreach (Player p2 in group5)
            {
                if (p1 != p2)
                {
                    if (group5.IndexOf(p1) > group5.IndexOf(p2))
                    {
                        Game game = new Game(tournamentID, p1.id, p2.id);
                        game.status = "Pending";
                        gm.CreateGame(game);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    else if (i == 5)
    {
        foreach (Player p1 in group6)
        {
            foreach (Player p2 in group6)
            {
                if (p1 != p2)
                {
                    if (group6.IndexOf(p1) > group6.IndexOf(p2))
                    {
                        Game game = new Game(tournamentID, p1.id, p2.id);
                        game.status = "Pending";
                        gm.CreateGame(game);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the code for different if statements is literally the same but the only difference is in using different lists with similar name (group1, group2..).

Comment: Look a like you need a `foreach(var group in new[] { group1, group2 ...group6})` or better yet use a `groups` array or list instead of numbered variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In General

This comes up a lot. No; you cannot programmatically build a variable name. By the time the code is compiled the variable names are gone anyway

If you ever have variables with names like

```
something1
something2
something3
```

etc, then this is a candidate for using an array but remember arrays start from 0

```
var something = new Thing[3];
```

(In your case the Thing is e.g. a Player)

Now you can have a fixed part and a varying part in your name:

```
Before you had    Now you have
--------------    ------------
something1        something[0]
something2        something[1]
something3        something[2]
```

Arrays can be looped over with a `for` or `foreach`, and they can be accessed at random with hard coded indexes like above. Just like your code only having 3 variables named `somethingX` your array also has a fixed number of 3 values. Arrays don't grow

If you need something that works like an array but does grow, use a List:

```
var something = new List<Thing>();
```

This is a list of Thing, just like before you had an array of Thing.

---

Also, don't forget about dictionaries, which are like lists, in that they grow, but they can be indexed by anything, so you can programmatically build an index, and unlike arrays/lists which are indexed by an incrementing integer, a dictionary can skip out some indexes:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, Thing>();
```

This means "a dictionary indexed by an int and holding a Thing"

Now, this is possible:

```
dict[1] = new Thing();
dict[2] = new Thing();
dict[4] = new Thing(); //we skipped
```

The key can be anything, for example a string:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Thing>();
dict["something1"] = new Thing();
dict["something2"] = new Thing();
dict["sometheng4"] = new Thing(); //watch out for typos!
```

You can programmatically build the key:

```
int x = 1;
dict["something"+x].SomePropertyOfThing = "Hello";
```

The only thing to note is that dictionary doesn't necessarily store it's contents in any kind of order. If you `foreach` it you might get the entries out in `something2, sometheng4, something1` order. If you need order, you either have to sort the `dict.Keys` and then use it to access the dictionary, or you use a SortedDictionary or OrderedDictionary depending what you want

---

In summary, those are the main kinds of collections we use in C#; they have different strengths and weaknesses and choosing which to use in a situation is often an important engineering decision

Final point of note; strive to use plural names when working with collections, as it makes the code easier to reason about

### Specifically in this case

In your particular case you're actually looking for an array of arrays, and a bit of LINQ might make your code easier to deal with:

```
var groups = new []{ group1, group2, group3 };

foreach(var g in groups)
  foreach(var p1 in g)
    foreach(var p2 in g.Where(p => p.id > p1.id)) 
      gm.CreateGame(new Game(tournamentID, p1.id, p2.id){status = "Pending"});
```

If you want to make just one tournament for a particular group N, replace the `foreach(var g in groups)` with `var g = groups[N]`

---

This logic you have of "for each player 1, for each player 2, if they aren't the same player, find the index of the player 1, find the index of the player 2, if the one index is less than the two index" contains redundant logic, and it wastes resources finding things it has already found

Saying "for every player1 in the group, for every player2 whose id is greater than player1" cuts all that out. Player 2 must be a different player to Player 1 because their id is greater. There is no need to look up the index; you could shortcut your code to comparing the IDs rather than doing a notequals check then finding indexes then comparing

If your ID values aren't intrinsically comparable in a greater than sense for some reason (I assumed they would be ints) you can use a bit more linq to assign an index i to each player p in a group:

```
var groups = new []{
  group1.Select((p,i) => (p,i)),
  group2.Select((p,i) => (p,i)),
  group3.Select((p,i) => (p,i))
};
```

This make a tuple of the player, and the index they're at, so a similar logic as before can work:

```
foreach(var g in groups)
  foreach(var p1t in g)
    foreach(var p2t in g.Where(pt => pt.i > p1t.i)) 
      gm.CreateGame(new Game(tournamentID, p1t.p.id, p2t.p.id){status = "Pending"});
```

This time the Where demands the index i be greater for player 2

You should name your properties using PascalCase, not camelCase

Answer (score 1):

As has already been suggested, you could collect all your groups in an array, and then iterate over that group array:

```csharp
List<Player>[] groups = new[] { group1, group2, group3, group4, group5, group6 };

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    // play games
}
```

I would like to suggest a simplification of your logic as well. You can achieve the same result using fewer nested loops by only looping through the necessary combinations of **player 1** and **player 2** in each group.

One way to do this is to:

- loop over the players' list indices rather than the `Player` objects in the lists (i.e. replace your nested `foreach (Player p*)` loops with nested `for (int i*)` (player index) loops)
- let the outer loop (looping over the indices for **player 1**) iterate over the current group from `0` to the second-to-last-index
- let the inner loop (looping over the indices for **player 2**) iterate over the current group from *one index larger than the index of **player 1*** to the very last index

Implementation:

```csharp
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < group.Count - 1; i1++)
    {
        Player p1 = group[i1];

        for (int i2 = i1 + 1; i2 < group.Count; i2++)
        {
            Player p2 = group[i2];

            Game game = new Game(tournamentID, p1.id, p2.id);
            game.status = "Pending";
            gm.CreateGame(game);
        }
    }
}
```

If we refer to the index of **player 1** simply as **1** and the index of **player 2** simply as **2**, the iterations over a group containing four players can be visualized as follows:

> **1** **2** _ _
> **1** _ **2** _
> **1** _ _ **2**
>
> _ **1** **2** _
> _ **1** _ **2**
>
> _ _ **1** **2**

---

If you rather want the games to be created in the exact same order of player combinations as is done in your original post, the index conditions need to be altered so that `p2` always comes before `p1` in the group:

> **2** **1** _ _
>
> **2** _ **1** _
> _ **2** **1** _
>
> **2** _ _ **1**
> _ **2** _ **1**
> _ _ **2** **1**

This can be achieved by altering the `for loop` statements slightly:

- the index of **player 1** goes from `1` to the very last index in the group
- the index of **player 2** goes from `0` to *one index smaller than the index of **player 1***

```csharp
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    for (var i1 = 1; i1 < group.Count; i1++)
    {
        //

        for (var i2 = 0; i2 < i1; i2++)
        {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

---

To ensure you are not trying to perform invalid looping on any of the groups, you could alter the `foreach` statement to consider the length of each group; either by using `.Skip(1).Any()` from the *System.Linq* namespace:

```csharp
//using System.Linq;

foreach (var group in groups.Where(gr => gr.Skip(1).Any()))
{
    // play games
}
```

or by counting the items in each group:

```csharp
foreach (var group in groups.Where(gr => gr.Count > 1))
{
    // play games
}
```

We're checking that the number of items in each group is greater than 1 (i.e. the number of items is at least 2), seeing as we want to play games with two players at a time.

Answer (score 0):

create a list of grpups

```
 var groups = new List<Group>(){
     group1, group1, group3};
```

now you can do

```
  if(group[i].Indexof.....)
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

Just make an array of your groups, assuming they are `List<Player>` below, and iterate over that:

```
foreach(var grp in new List<Player>[] {group1, group2, group3, group4, group5, group6}) {
    foreach (Player p1 in grp)
    {
        foreach (Player p2 in grp)
        {
            if (p1 != p2)
            {
                if (grp.IndexOf(p1) > grp.IndexOf(p2))
                {
                    Game game = new Game(tournamentID, p1.id, p2.id);
                    game.status = "Pending";
                    gm.CreateGame(game);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```